# How Pass parameters to JMES path expression in python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, boto3, jmespath

Python code.
How to pass parameters to JMESpath instead of hardcoding?

```
ext= '.md'
filtered_iterator = page_iterator.search("Contents[?ends_with(Key, `.md`)].Key")
```

I would like to pass ext paramters in the contents path in the place of `.md`.
What will be the possible way?

Answer (score 1):

```
ext= '.md'
filtered_iterator = page_iterator.search("Contents[?ends_with(Key, `%s`)].Key" % ext)
```